# Set treeview virtualization to true by default in a custom control

Tags: wpf, treeview, virtualization

Is there a way of setting the virtualisation of a custom control derived from a treeview to true by default?  For example, I have a custom control derived from a RadTreeView:

```
public class MyTreeViewControl : RadTreeView
{
    static MyTreeViewControl()
    {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(MyTreeViewControl), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(MyTreeViewControl)));
    }
}
```

and a Generic.Xaml file with the following:

```
<ResourceDictionary
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:userControls="clr-namespace:HDC.Solus.WPF.UserControls"
xmlns:telerik="http://schemas.telerik.com/2008/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:classes="clr-namespace:HDC.Solus.WPF.Classes">

<HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type classes:MyTreeViewItem}" ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Image Height="16" Width="16" Source="{Binding IconUri}" />
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}" />
    </StackPanel>
</HierarchicalDataTemplate>

<Style TargetType="{x:Type userControls:MyTreeViewControl}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type telerik:RadTreeView}}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type userControls:MyTreeViewControl}">
                <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="telerik:TreeViewPanel.IsVirtualizing" Value="True"/>
</Style>
```

However, the virtualisation is not enabled by default, the only way of getting the virtualisation enabled is to set it directly on the control when creating it, for example:

```
<userControls:MyTreeViewControl IsVirtualizing="True" />
```

Comment: Just curious... why is it Setter Property="telerik:TreeViewPanel.IsVirtualizing"? Does using VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="True" in the style not work?

Comment: I tried that but gave the error "Property 'IsVirtualizing' is not attachable to elements of type 'ResourceDictionary'".  The above code is in the Generic.Xaml that gets created when you create a custom control.

Comment: Can you post your MyTreeViewControl?

Comment: I've updated the main question to include the code in the two files, cheers...

Answer (score 0):

I haven't worked with this too much... but will replacing Treeviewpanel or some template with one of your choosing not work?  if you can't set it in xaml.

If you want to override default metadata of controls you can do something like this in the constructor.  Not sure if it will help though

```
TreeView.ItemsPanelProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(MyTreeViewControl), new PropertyMetadata(myNewItemsPanel));
```

This is how you normally change dependency property of the inherited object.

You might also want to create an "IsVirtualizing dependency property in your custom control and then either in "OnApplyTemplate" Bind the property to telerik:TreeViewPanel.IsVirtualizing property.  Or alternatively Bind in telerik:TreeViewPanel.IsVirtualizing property in XAML to newly created Is Virtualizing dependency property.

Hope you get it solved :)